# Determinant as a combination of ALL minors of dimension $N-1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A = (a_{i,j})_{1\leq i,j\leq N}$ be a matrix of dimension $n$. If we denote by $A_{i,j}$ the minor of the matrix, it is well known that $$ |A| = \sum_{i=1}^N (-1)^{i+j}A_{i,j}a_{i,j}$$ for every $1\leq j \leq N.$ I remember to read in a book that, in fact,
$$ |A| = \sum_{i=1}^N \left( \sum_{m=1}^N (-1)^{i+m}A_{i,m} \right) a_{i,j}$$ for every $1\leq j \leq N$, but I cannot get a proof of this result. Really, I do not know if this result is true at all, I have checked it for $N=2$ and $N=3$ but I have some problems to get the result for an arbitrary dimension $N$.

Anyone can help me? I just need some references to check the proof!

Thank you very much!

EDIT: After some research, I found a result in 'Dale & Vein, Determinants and their Applications in Mathematical Physics' called the Alien Cofactor Theorem that states:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N a_{i,j}A_{i,k} = 0$$ for every $1\leq j \leq N$, $1\leq j \leq N$, $k\neq j.$ A direct application of this result yields the result, but the book does not include any references about the proof. Does anyone know any references for the proof?

Comment: If you sum your first equation over $j$, does that give you what you want?

Comment: If we sum the first equation over j, we do not obtain the second one: for the first equation we would get the sum over i,j of A_{i,j}a_{i,j}, meanwhile for the second we will have cross products of the form A_{i,m}a_{i,j}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Alien Cofactor Theorem* states:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^N (-1)^{i+m}A_{im}\,a_{ij}=0 \qquad\text{ if }\quad m\neq j, \tag{1}$$

and symmetrically swapping rows with columns. Combining this with Laplace's theorem, we can write

$$ \sum_{i=1}^N (-1)^{i+m}A_{im}\,a_{ij}=\det(A)\,\delta_{mj}, $$

where $\,\delta_{mj}\,$ is the Kronecker delta.

Proof of $(1)$:$\quad$ Fixed $\,m\,$ and $\,j,\,$ let $\,A'=(a'_{hk})\,$ be the matrix defined by:

$$ a'_{hm}=a_{hj} \qquad\text{and}\qquad a'_{hk}=a_{hk} \quad\text{for}\quad k\neq m, $$

i.e. $A'$ is obtained from $A$ by replacing the $m$-th column with the $j$-th column, leaving the other columns unchanged (including the $j$-th). Note that the $(i,m)-$minor $A'_{im}$ of $A'$ is equal to the minor $A_{im}$ of $A$, and $\,(1)\,$ gives then

$$ \sum_{i=1}^N(-1)^{i+m}A_{im}\,a_{ij} = \sum_{i=1}^N(-1)^{i+m}A'_{im}\,a'_{im} = \det(A') = 0 $$

by the Laplace's Theorem, and because $\,\det(A')=0,\,$ having $\,A'\,$ two equal columns, $\quad$ q.e.d.

Now your thesis follows:

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^N\left(\sum_{m=1}^N(-1)^{i+m}A_{im}\right)a_{ij} &= \sum_{m=1}^N\left(\sum_{i=1}^N(-1)^{i+m}A_{im}a_{ij}\right) = \\[1.5ex]
&=\sum_{m=1}^N\det(A)\delta_{mj} = \det(A).
\end{align}